# NSArray index beyond bounds error

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, indexing, nsarray

I have created a simple image browser with two buttons to view the next and the previous images.

[image]

Here's the code.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *images;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSInteger imageIndex;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBarButtonItem *nextButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIBarButtonItem *prevButon;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Adding Next and Previous buttons
    self.nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"next"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(nextButtonPressed)];
    self.prevButon = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"previous"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(previousButtonPressed)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = @[self.nextButton, self.prevButon];


    // Loading images
    self.images = @[
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"1"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"2"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"3"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"4"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"5"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"6"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"7"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"8"],
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"9"]
                    ];

    self.imageIndex = 0;
    self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex];
}

- (void)nextButtonPressed
{
    self.imageIndex++;
    self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex];
}

- (void)previousButtonPressed
{
    self.imageIndex--;
    self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex];
}

@end
```

My problem is say if I tap next button after the last image or previous button when the first image, it'll throw a index beyond bounds error.

How can I stop this from happening?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check whether the index is present in your index.
You can make the verification in your `nextButtonPressed` and `previousButtonPressed` methods:

```
- (void)nextButtonPressed
{
    if (imageIndex < ([self.images count] - 1))
    {
        self.imageIndex++;
        self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex];
    }
}

- (void)previousButtonPressed
{
    if (imageIndex >= 1)
    {
        self.imageIndex--;
        self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex];
    }
}
```

For information the NSArray raises an `NSRangeException` if the index is beyond the end of the array (see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/objectAtIndex%3a)).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Your solution works perfectly. Can you please tell me how to disable the buttons when I reach the ends of the array?

Comment: The most simple is to create a method ``layoutButtons`` for example, in which you disable the buttons is you reach the end of the array. Call these method each time you call the ``nextButtonPressed`` and the ``previousButtonPressed``, and also at the end of your ``viewDidLoad`` for the initial state.

Answer (score 1):

You are keeping track of the current image index, which is good, because you can use that to check if there is a next image or a previous by using the image arrays count property.

```
- (void)nextButtonPressed
{
    if ( self.imageIndex < self.images.count - 1) {
         self.imageIndex++;
         self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex];
    }
}

- (void)previousButtonPressed
{
    if ( self.imageIndex > 0 ) {
        self.imageIndex--;
        self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex];
    }
}
```

Another alternative is starting over when you reach the last image.

```
- (void)nextButtonPressed
{
    if ( self.imageIndex < self.images.count - 1) {
         self.imageIndex++;
    } else {
         self.imageIndex = 0
    }
    self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex];
}

- (void)previousButtonPressed
{
    if ( self.imageIndex > 0 ) {
        self.imageIndex--;
    } else {
        self.imageIndex = self.images.count - 1;
    }
    self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A good UI habit will be to disable the next (or previous) button once you reach the last image (and of course prevent the overflow in the array):

```
- (void)nextButtonPressed
{    
    self.imageIndex++;
    self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex];

    [self.previousButton setEnabled:YES];

    if (self.imageIndex == [self.images count] - 1) {
        [self.nextButton setEnabled:NO];

        return ;
    } 
}

- (void)previousButtonPressed
{
   self.imageIndex--;
   self.imageView.image = self.images[self.imageIndex];

   [self.nextButton setEnabled:YES];

   if (self.imageIndex == 0) {
       [self.previousButton setEnabled:NO];

       return ;
   } 
}
```

Since you start with `index = 0` you should disable the previous button in `viewDidLoad` method (as you do not have more previous images until you press next) or do it directly in IB if possible

Comment: I thought of disabling buttons too. That was actually my next step. I tried out your code. It works but has some flaws too. For example, if I tap the previous button as soon as the app starts, it crashes. Also when I reach the last image, the next button gets disabled which is correct but when I go back, that button remains disabled.

Comment: You are correct, I edited my answer, now you will be able to disable/enable correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **modulus** like this - so it wraps around on itself.
This way you never need to disable buttons and it also makes it **easier** for the **user** to get from one end of the list to the other more efficiently.

replace the following line

```
self.imageIndex++;
```

with

```
self.imageIndex = (self.imageIndex + 1) % [self.images count];
```

and where you have the following line

```
self.imageIndex--;
```

replace with

```
self.imageIndex = (self.imageIndex + [self.images count] - 1) % [self.images count];
```